# Mechanics: Direction of force acting on a hinge

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, conventions, free-body-diagram

I'm having trouble with the direction of force acting on hinges. For example:

Why is Cx's and Cy's direction so in parts 2 and 3? And isn't H a hinge as well why is there only a force acting in the y direction and not x?

[image]

And this:

[image]

I always choose the wrong directions when it comes to hinges. Is there an easy way to determine them? Not asking for the answer to the questions.

Comment: In general you pick a direction which simplifies the problem and an arbitrary sense (what is negative or positive). Just make sure you apply equal and opposite forces on the two parts connected by the hinge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not understood your examples. The first is too difficult to read, and without further explanation it is not clear what is wrong with your choice of directions. There is not enough information to understand what might be wrong with $C_x$ and $C_y$, nor to identify hinge $H$.

Generally it does not make any difference which direction you choose. If the solution gives you a -ve value the direction is the reverse of the one you have chosen. If you think there should be a component of force in both $x$ and $y$ directions, include both components in your analysis. If you are wrong the solution will tell you that one component is zero.